# Change tab width in emacs

Tags: emacs

I added lines from this website
https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IndentationBasics
to my `~/.emacs` file:

```
  (setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
  (setq tab-width 4)
  (defvaralias 'c-basic-offset 'tab-width)
```

And it made my tabs in `.h` files and `.cpp` files 8 spaces long (before they were 2 spaces long).
How to make them 4 spaces long?

Comment: Calling `defvaralias` on existing variables is **evil**.  It will sooner or later eat up all your karma and bite you in the you-know-what.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Both `tab-width` and `c-basic-offset` variables are buffer-local, which means it is effective only in the buffer you set it. Emacs only evaluates `~/.emacs` at start up, and it is only effective in that file.

To set a default value for all buffers, you need

```
(setq-default tab-width 4)
```